# Regex contiguous match

Tags: regex, expression

I have the following mathematical expression `ii*3+(ii*2)+xdii+13-ii-ii-4` and I want to replace every occurence of the variable `ii` for `ii[x]`. Obviously xdii is not to be replaced, since it is another variable.

The problem is that the resulting output is: `ii[x]*3+(ii[x]*2)+xdii+13-ii[x]-ii-4`. So my problem is that when the regex engine is replacing `-ii-ii` it only replaces the first occurence of those two consecutive matches. Here is my regex,

```
's/([\+\*\-\s\(]|^)ii([\+\*\-\s\)])/$1ii[x]$2/'
```

If the mathematical expression had one extra space between those two consecutives, then the result woul be correct. For example:`ii*3+(ii*2)+xdii+13-ii- ii-4` yields the correct answer.

In case it helps i am appending the regex debug internal output when the engine reaches the second occurence of `-ii-ii`

```
Guessing start of match, REx `([\+\*\-\s\(]|^)ii([\+\*\-\s\)])' against `ii-4'...
Found floating substr `ii' at offset 0...
Guessed: match at offset 0
Matching REx `([\+\*\-\s\(]|^)ii([\+\*\-\s\)])' against `ii-4'
  Setting an EVAL scope, savestack=0
  23 <i+13-ii-> <ii-4>    |  1:  OPEN1
  23 <i+13-ii-> <ii-4>    |  3:  BRANCH
  Setting an EVAL scope, savestack=7
  23 <i+13-ii-> <ii-4>    |  4:    ANYOF[\11-\15 (*+\-]
                              failed...
  23 <i+13-ii-> <ii-4>    | 15:    BOL
                              failed...
  Clearing an EVAL scope, savestack=0..7
Match failed
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `null width matches`. Usually:

> ```
>     The  symbols  \< and \> respectively match the empty string at the beginning 
> and end of a word.  The symbol \b matches the empty string at the edge
> of a word, and \B matches the empty string provided it's not 
> at the edge of a word.  The symbol \w is a  synonym  for  [_[:alnum:]]  and  \W  is  a
> synonym for [^_[:alnum:]].
> ```

So in you case `\<ii\>` will be the right thing to replace
But check with the docs of matcher you are using.

Comment: based on your answer i modified my regex to

Comment: 's/([\+\*\-\s\(]|^|\b)ii([\+\*\-\s\)]|\b)/$1ii[x]$2/' and works perfectly

Comment: @FranciscoJuretig Actually I can't see why do you need such a complex expression. Most 'replacement tools' (the perl operator, or php lib call, or whatever) are capable to make several replacements in one shot. When you start your string has no occurrences of ii with subscript. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your character class: The hyphen must appear either first or last, otherwise it will signify a *range*. Although to be honest I don't know what happens if the range includes a character *type* `\s`.

Try this:

```
s/([+*\s(-]|^)ii([+*\s)-])/$1ii[x]$2/
```

Comment: your comment is absolutely correct, and totally agree with you. Nevertheless, the problem is not solved. I needed to add  a |\b in order to solve the problem